# How to notify ListAdapter

Tags: android

Is there any way to notify ListAdapter? Because i need to load Tab content data when user click in that Tab.

Thanks
Chandana

Comment: What sort of `ListAdapter` is this? What is the "Tab content data"? What do you mean by "user click in that Tab"?

Comment: I have 3 tab. when user loading one tab, i need to reload it data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you can do it like this:

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```